# Replaced matched text in Vim with pattern

Tags: text-processing, vim, search

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.  Start with:

```
"this")
"that")
[hundreds of lines like this]
```

End with:

```
"this",&this)
"that",&that)
[hundreds of lines like this]
```

I have gotten this far:

```
g/"\p*"/s/)/[what to put here?]
```

So it correctly identifies the string that I want to copy.  What I'm not sure is how to tell it that I want it to paste that string at the end.  I've tried using `&`, but that matches the `)`, not the `"\p*"`.

Comment: `:%s/"\(.*\)")/"\1",\&\1)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you just use a search and replace on every line?

```
:% s/"\([a-z]*\)"/"\1"\,\&\1/g
```